# could someone explain the source code of toString method which is overridden in the String class?

Tags: java, string, object, reference, tostring

I have few questions it would be helpful if someone answered it.

1. What does the toString() method returns in the following code?

   ```
   /** 
   * This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned. 
   * 
   * @return the string itself.
   */ 
   public String toString() {
   return this; 
   }
   ```

As you can see the above method returns **this** which means the reference of the object on which it is called is returned, then if we print a String object, automatically the toString() method is called and the reference is returned to println() method ,but we are getting the output as  value(Mango) not the reference (let's say the memory address would be dtt22723836@dtf).

If  **this** (reference) is returned, then the output should be the following

```
String a="Mango";
System.out.println(a);
/* Actual output : Mango
My assumption :dtt22723836@dtf (as the reference is returned from toString() 
to println()
 */
```

2. what is stored in the reference variable of a String? value(Mango) or the reference(dtt22723836@dtf)?

correct me if I'm wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Which expressions is (or should be) printed as `dtt22723836@dtf`? That's not clear.

Comment: Actually it is not a expression it is just an example as as an reference (memory address)

Comment: When you call `a.toString()`, the word `this` inside `toString` means exactly the same thing as `a`. I _think_ that's where you are confused. Let me ask you this, if you think `System.out.println(a);` should print out `dtt22723836@dtf`, what code do you think should print out the actual contents of the string - `Mango`?

Comment: See the `toString()` implementation of Object class. You'll be more clarified.

Comment: @Sweeper That is the main confusion . Because I didn't actually see a single information on what is stored in the reference variable of the String object?

Comment: The variable stores a reference to the `String` object, but that fact is not really relevant here. `println` is supposed to know how to print the contents of the string you passed to it. It is _not_ supposed to print something like `java.lang.String@ab2323`. If it did, your JDK has a bug.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be looking at it from a strange angle. There's one fact that you need to start with: `System.out.println()` *knows how* to show the actual text content of a `String` object.
This means that when you give it a `String`, it will print the text of a string (`"Mango"`, and not something like `java.lang.String@ab2323`). It's only when you give it a non-`String` Object that it calls `toString()` method (via `String.valueOf()` - although `valueOf` seems to be called even in `println(String)`, supposedly to deal with nulls too).

The text `"dtt22723836@dtf"` is usually the `String` object created by the `toString()` method implemented in `java.lang.Object` (and not overridden in subclasses) - `println()` calls this method to get the string to print.

Now, `String a = "Mango"` *is already* a `String`, meaning that `System.out.println(a)` knows how to print the text content, which is `Mango` rather than any fabrication from `java.lang.Object.toString()` default implementation.

This is why `java.lang.String.toString()` does nothing but return the object on which the `toString()` method is called. It's already a `String` object, when it is returned, it's used by `println()` in predictable ways.

`java.lang.String.toString()` has nothing to compute, the object itself is a `String`. *The End*.

Comment: But one last doubt , does the println(a) call the toString() method? and what is the purpose of toString() method which is overridden in String class?

Comment: @SangeethaM Whether `println(String)` calls `toString` is an implementation detail, which means "depends on the JDK". On my version of the JDK, it does call `toString`. OTOH, `println(Object)` definitely calls `toString` (indirectly via `String.valueOf`). You are calling the former overload in your code. `toString` is overridden because the value that the default implementation returns (such as `java.lang.String@ab2323`) doesn't make much sense. You wouldn't expect `"abc".toString()` to give you `java.lang.String@ab2323`, would you?

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` method is specified to return a `String`, so the instance of `String` just returns itself. (It could create a new instance, but that would still be a `String`).

On the other end, the `println(String)` method (from `PrintStream`) ends up calling the `getChars()` method of `String` to print that characters. The `println(String)` method is called if the argument is a `String`, for other reference types `println(Object)` method is called, This the one is the one that uses `toString` to get the textual representation of its argument.

Answer (score 1):

The toString method gets called inside the println method.

The first line in println(Object x):

```
String s = String.valueOf(x);
```

And String.valueOf(Object obj) calls:

```
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

Note: If the class doesn't override the toString method NOT the address will get printed but an unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object combined with the class name an an @.